# Which way is better to pass arrays as function arguments in C?

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

There are 3 ways to pass arrays as function arguments.

- Formal parameters as **a pointer**, e.g., `void myFunction(int *param) {}`
- Formal parameters as **a sized array**, e.g., `void myFunction(int param[10]) {}`
- Formal parameters as **an unsized array**, e.g., `void myFunction(int param[]) {}`

Which way is better in terms of efficiency and readability?

Comment: Difference is only for human eyes, not for compiler though. Everything will be treated as `void myFunction(int *param)` by the compiler.

Comment: Opinion-based, but I'd argue the first is better as the last two imply that there's some sort of special array typing going on that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: If the array is fixed size the (arguably) best method is to take a pointer to an array of this size because it will provide typechecking. like in `void foo(int (*p)[10])`

Comment: [Door #4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Make_a_Deal#Big_Deal): `void myFunction(size_t array_element_count, int *param);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think it should go instead of all the others anyway :) None of the listed methods let the function know the size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which way is better to pass arrays as function arguments in C?

I am going for [Door #4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Make_a_Deal#Big_Deal).  The receiving function needs to know the size.

```
void myFunction(size_t array_element_count, int *param);
```

Alternatively code could use a terminating sentinel, but there are no special "I-am-not-an-int" values.

In terms of the below, they emit the same code.  This is a style issue.  As such, follow the group's style guide.  For me I favor `size_t array_element_count, int param[array_element_count]` as most informative to code's intent.

```
void myFunction(size_t array_element_count, int *param);
void myFunction(size_t array_element_count, int param[array_element_count]);
void myFunction(size_t array_element_count, int param[]);
```

---

In terms of style, `f(size, ptr)` vs `f(ptr, size)`, I recall reading on the next C rev promoting `f(size, ptr)`.  IAC,  with more complex arrays and VLA support , the below  is useful:

```
foo(size_t row, size_t col, matrix[row][col]);
```

Comment: This is only a stylistic point (but then, so is the question), but I'd put the size after the pointer, for consistency with the argument order generally used by the standard library functions.

Comment: @ray Although STL tends that way, I think things are going the opposite.  IAC, using sizes first is useful with VLA.

Comment: For my money, I'd go with `void myFunction(size_t array_element_count, int param[array_element_count]);` because it documents the expected size of the array and is flexible enough to handle any size of array.  The compiler converts the function declaration to `void myFunction(size_t array_element_count, int param[*]);`.  I regard the VLA notation as particularly valuable when dealing with different sizes of multi-dimensional array.  Using names instead of `*` should inform the user (programmer using the function) how to write the calls.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler We are in high agreement.

Answer (score 4):

All three notations are equivalent, which makes the sized array declaration very confusing:

With `void myFunction(int param[10]);` you will not get strong type checking and `sizeof(param)` will be the size of an `int*` pointer, not that of the array passed to the function. Avoid this notation for these reasons.

C99 introduced a new syntax to specify that a pointer argument must point to an array of at least a certain number of items:

```
void myFunction(int param[static 10]);
```

This notation is not very common and compilers do not fully check the size constraint that it implies. Note also that `sizeof(param)` is still that of a pointer. So part of the confusion remains.

For readability, I would suggest using `void myFunction(int *param);` if `param` points to an `int` variable and `void myFunction(int param[]);` if `param` points to an array of `int`. The size of this array should be passed as a separate argument.

With this convention, I usually define `main` as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as the compiler is concerned, there is no difference.

Section 6.7.6.3p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Function Declarators states:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array oftype’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer totype’’,  where  the  type  qualifiers  (if  any)
>   are  those  specified  within  the `[` and `]` of  the array  type 
>   derivation.   If  the  keyword `static` also  appears  within  the `[`
>   and `]` of  the array  type  derivation,  then  for  each  call  to 
>   the  function,  the  value  of  the  corresponding actual argument
>   shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as
>   many elements as specified by the size expression.

So `int *param`, `int param[10]`, and `int param[]` as functions parameters are exactly equivalent.  The only difference is in terms of readability.

Generally, I would use the array syntax without the size if an array is expected so it's clearer to the reader what the parameter is for.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size at compile time and can do it (e.g., because you aren't passing a pointer to a subarray), then I would say

```
struct ints10 { int ints10[10]; };
void myFunction(struct ints10 *param);
```

because that can be strongly type-checked and `sizeof` will work on the destination as expected.

Otherwise

```
void myFunction(int param[10]);
void myFunction(int param[2]);
     //doesn't matter that the sizing is inconsistent here
     //the (innermost, e.g., if you have `int a[2][3][4]` in a param, it gets adjusted to `int (*a)[3][4]`) size is 
     //is adjusted to a pointer and isn't checked (comptime or runtime)
     //for consistency only for positiveness (comptime)
void myFunction(int param[]);
void myFunction(int *param);
```

are all fully compatible as far as typechecking is concerned because of how array arguments are adjusted to pointers.

I would recommend being as descriptive as possible (i.e., `int param[10]`) but keep in mind that the innermost index of an array specified as parameter is adjusted to a pointer, which means the size in it is only as good as a comment (except that the contents of it is syntactically checked and verified as a positive integer).

As far as codegeneration is concerned, all mentioned forms should generate the same assembly even on a not-very-smart compiler.

If you don't know the size at compile time, then you need an extra parameter for passing it, but passing it otherwise will make the function a tiny bit less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of a *function parameter declaration*, all three versions are treated exactly the same way.

Remember that under most circumstances<sup>1</sup> array *expressions* "decay" to pointer expressions - that is, if you have something like

```
char arr[10];
foo( arr );
```

the expression `arr` in the call to `foo` "decays" from type "10-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", so what `foo` actually receives is an argument of type `char *`:

```
void foo( char *a ) { ... }
```

As a "convenience", you may declare `a` as `char a[10]` or `char a[]`, but they will be interpreted as `char *a`.

---

1. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T` and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.